# How to import shp2pgsql on mac?

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I am using EnterpriseDB to run Postgis.

when I run "shp2pgsql" on got an error message.

```
~ macbook$ shp2pgsql
-bash: shp2pgsql: command not found
~ macbook$ which shp2pgsql
```

I read that I should find it in this directory, but It seems that I am missing that file.

~ macbook$ ls /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/

```
clusterdb       pg_controldata      pgbench
createdb        pg_ctl          pgsql2shp
createlang      pg_dump         pltcl_delmod
createuser      pg_dumpall      pltcl_listmod
dropdb          pg_isready      pltcl_loadmod
droplang        pg_receivexlog      postgres
dropuser        pg_resetxlog        postmaster
ecpg            pg_restore      psql
initdb          pg_standby      raster2pgsql
oid2name        pg_test_fsync       reindexdb
pg_archivecleanup   pg_test_timing      shp2pgsql
pg_basebackup       pg_upgrade      vacuumdb
pg_config       pg_xlogdump     vacuumlo
```

when I run this comma
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql.sh Outlines.shp city | psql -d City

It says: 
-bash: psql: command not found
-bash: shp2pgsql.sh: command not found

How can I run this command ? 
should I go for shp2pgsql-gui loader ?

Comment: Maybe add that folder to your PATH. How to do that is not GIS specific.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the EnterpriseDB installer before, so I'm not sure if it installs shp2pgsql by default.

You can confirm whether or not you do have shp2pgsql installed, however, by performing the following commands:

```
# Update your search database
$ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
# Execute search for shp2pgsql
$ locate shp2pgsql
```

The output of this command for me is as follows:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-2:scripts matt$ locate shp2pgsql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.1/bin/shp2pgsql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.1/share/man/man1/shp2pgsql.1
/usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
/usr/local/share/man/man1/shp2pgsql.1
```

Looking more specifically at /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql on my system, we can see that it's symbolically linked to /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.1/bin/shp2pgsql

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-2:scripts matt$ ls -lath /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
lrwxr-xr-x  1 matt  admin    37B Dec  7 20:31 /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql -> ../Cellar/postgis/2.1.1/bin/shp2pgsql
```

So, if the output of the locate command on your Mac shows that shp2pgsql has been installed, but is not in your /usr/local/bin directory, you might be able to get away with creating the symlink in /usr/local/bin, pointing it to the actual file path to shp2pgsql.

See this link on creating symlinks: http://justinwalker.me/2012/02/better-than-an-alias-create-a-symbolic-link-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: after following your instructions, i got this prob: dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib

Comment: Same issue, but with OpenGeo Suite it's installed in /usr/local/opengeo/bin/shp2pgsql. I'm adding `usr/local/opengeo/bin` to my PATH

Answer (score 0):

I got the same

dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib

Full Code:

Last login: Mon Feb 10 18:19:48 on ttys000
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ Danny$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout

[Process completed]

Comment: How did you solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (I can now run the tool though I've not yet loaded any data) is to add an export line to your `~/.bash_login` file (assuming you're using `bash`):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```